# Sorting STDIN by length and number of nonblanks in a Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell-script, sort

I am working on learning Bash scripting but I am struggling with this problem. Given a bunch of lines from `STDIN`, sort them first by the length of the line in increasing order. Then, if there are any lines with the same number of characters, sort them by the number of nonblank characters contained in the lines (also in increasing order).

I've tried this a couple of different ways but I usually get caught up in some of the idiosyncrasies of Bash.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

sorted=()
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    length=${#line}
    if [[ ${sorted[$length]} == "" ]] ; then
        sorted[$length]="$line"
    else
        #non unique length
        #sorted[$length]="${sorted[$length]}\n$line"
        IFS=$'\n' arr=("${sorted[$length]}")
        arr+=("$line")

        spaces=()

        for ((i=0 ; i < ${#arr[@]} ; ++i )) ; do
            spaces[$i]=$(echo "${arr[$i]}" | sed "s: : \n:g" | grep -c " ")
        done

        arr_sorted=()

        for ((i =0 ; i < ${#spaces[@]} ; i++ )) ; do
                for ((j=0 ; j < ${#arr[@]} ; i++ )) ; do

                        this_line_length=$(echo "${arr[$j]}" | sed "s: : \n:g" | grep -c " ")
                        if [[ "$this_line_length" == "${spaces[$i]}" ]] ; then
                            arr_sorted+=("${arr[$j]}")
                            unset arr[$j]
                        fi
                done
        done


    sorted[$length]="${arr_sorted[@]}"


    fi
done
```

I'm going to go ahead and guess this is nowhere near the best way to do it. I thought I would try to implement everything without relying too heavily on bash builtins but now it seems pretty pointless.

Comment: Please clarify what "*increasing order*" means... i.e. longest line first, or longest line last.

Comment: Cross-posted using a different account? https://askubuntu.com/questions/913199/sorting-in-bash-based-on-the-number-of-occurrence-of-a-specific-character

Comment: coud you post sample of *input `->` output*?

Comment: @muru, Same class, different students perhaps.  The answers for this Q seem a bit sharper.

Comment: See also: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 4):

If you're allowed to use evil external contraptions such as `sort` and `cut`:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    squeezed=$( tr -d '[:blank:]' <<<"$line" )
    printf '%d\t%d\t%s\n' ${#line} ${#squeezed} "$line"
done | sort -n -k 1 -k 2 | cut -f 3-
```

**Edit:** Since everybody's doing it, here's a solution with `perl`:

```
perl -e 'print sort { length $a <=> length $b || $a =~ y/ \t//c <=> $b =~ y/ \t//c } <>'
```

Comment: Our answers are nearly the same; yours is better for using *tab* separators, and `IFS= read -r`.  (Descriptive variables are a matter of taste.)

Comment: @agc Yeah, except mine was posted first. Not that I personally care, but there _are_ a few people here that like to make a fuss about these things. _shrug_

Comment: Being second, I'll delete mine if anybody cares.  It's not that... it's that *they're nearly the same* answer.  I've been slower by minutes before, but *never* with virtually the same code.  Details differ, but not the tools or method.

Answer (score 4):

Using the same principles as the others (get the line length, with and without whitespace characters, sort on those, and then remove them), but with `awk`:

```
awk '{NC = length(gensub(/[[:space:]]/, "", "g")); print length, NC, $0}' file |
  sort -nk1,2 |
  sed -r 's/^([0-9]+ ){2}//'
```

`gensub(/[[:space:]]/, "", "g")` deletes all whitespace characters in the line, and then we get the length of the remaining string

Using the question's text up to the code block, folded to 80 characters wide:

```
$ awk '{NC = length(gensub(/[[:space:]]/, "", "g")); print length, NC, $0}' foo | sort -nk1,2 | sed -r 's/^([0-9]+ ){2}//'


 increasing order).
Here's what I've got so far:
f the idiosyncrasies of bash.
iven a bunch of lines from STDIN, sort them first by the length of the line in i
I've tried this a couple of different ways but I usually get caught up in some o
, sort them by the number of nonblank characters contained in the lines (also in
I am working on learning bash scripting but I am struggling with this problem. G
ncreasing order. Then, if there are any lines with the same number of characters
```

Comment: You could avoid using the `gensub` GNUism with `gsub`. `gsub` also returns the number of substitutions made therefore you could shed the call to `length` and replace `-nk1,2` in the `sort` with `-k1,1n -k2,2nr`

Comment: @iruvar: but give gsub a different var that is a _copy_ of $0 (gensub does not modify its var but gsub and sub do)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, Drat! yes, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

With small input, this may be a lot quicker then other answer, as there is no forks!

```
sortByLength () { 
    local -a sorted=() sort2
    local line sline sline2 pointer
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        sorted[${#line}]+="$line."
    done
    for pointer in ${!sorted[@]} ;do
        sort2=()
        line="${sorted[pointer]}"
        while [ "$line" ]; do
            sline=${line:0:pointer}
            line=${line:pointer+1}
            sline2=${sline//[[:blank:]]}
            sort2[${#sline2}]+=${sline}$'\n'
        done
        printf "%s" "${sort2[@]}"
    done
}
```

As this look like a *homework*, I will let you explain how this work...

## With only 1 fork to [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

```
sortByLength () {
    perl -e '
        while(<>){
            chomp;
            push @a,$_;
        };
        map {
            printf "%s\n",${$_}[2];
        } sort {
            ${$a}[0]*1000+${$a}[1] <=> ${$b}[0]*1000+${$b}[1]
        }  map {
            my $s=$_;
            s/\s//g;
            [ length($s),length($_),$s ]
        } @a;
    '
}
```

Comment: Hmm, `printf "a b c\nabcde\nabcdefg\na\nabcd\n" | sortByLength` outputs in the 4th line a leading space that shouldn't be there.  Changing `sline2=${sline// }` to `sline2=${sline//}` seems to fix it, at least with that input.

Comment: @agc Thanks, there was a little bug; **corrected!**

Comment: This sorts the `bash` manual on my system in about 1.5 seconds.  The `zshall` manual (the complete manual for the `zsh` shell) takes 21.2 seconds to sort. This is not quick.  As a comparison, my own answer uses about 0.4 seconds to sort the `zshall` manual and half of that is used for just reading the data in.

Comment: I'm noticing that blank lines and lines containing tabs may be disappearing or be sorted wrong, respectively.  You may be interpreting "blank" as "space", in which case the issue with tabs in not important.  However, empty lines seems to go missing, and sometimes the code seems to insert the string `0:`.

Comment: @they You could add something like `line=${line//$'\t'/        }` just after `while IFS= read -r line; do` if you want to interpret *tabulation* as *eight spaces*, for sample.

Comment: @they *sometime*? Concatenating empty lines, preceding with number of character by line must produce `0: `, for any number of empty lines if at least one line is empty.

Comment: But a tab is a single character. It would be better if you changed `sline2=${sline// }` to `sline2=${sline//[[:blank:]]}`. The way I understood the question, no lines should be modified nor deleted, so deleting empty lines or converting them to a single line saying `0:` makes little sense to me.

Comment: @they I agree, re-reading the question, this is about *nonblank*. Answer edited.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't resist to add an `sed` solution:

```
sed 'h;s/.*/0:0;0123456789+/;G;:count
s/\(.\)\(;.*\1\)\(.\)\(.*\n\)[^[:space:]]/\3\2\3\4x/
s/\(.\)\(:.*\1\)\(.\)\(.*\n\)./\3\2\3\4/;:overflow
s/^+/10/;s/:+/:10/;s/\(.\)+\(.*\1\)\(.\)\(.*\n\)/\30\2\3\4/;t overflow
/\n./b count
G;s/;.*\n/:/' file|sort -t: -n -k 1 -k 2|cut -d: -f 3-
```

The `sed` script counts the chars and nonblanks and places them at the beginning of the line, `sort` and `cut` are straight forward.
And please don't tell me that this is nonsense. For me, it's fun. (-:

Answer (score 2):

Function:

```
sortlen() { while read x ; do \
              y=`tr -d '[:blank:]' <<< "$x"` ; echo ${#x} ${#y} "$x" ; \
            done | sort -k 1g,2 -k 2g,3 | cut -d' ' -f3-; }
```

Test:

```
printf "a b c\nabcde\nabcdefg\na\nabcd\n" | sortlen
```

Output:

```
a
abcd
a b c
abcde
abcdefg
```

Comment: I expect most people would consider 1, 4, 5, 5, 7 to be ascending order.    :-)    ⁠

Comment: @G-Man Oh, alright...

Answer (score -1):

I will be using standard `awk` to perform a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).  This involves prepending the line's length and the number of non-blank characters to each line, sorting the resulting lines on these two numbers, and removing them, leaving the original lines sorted in the way you prescribed.

```bsh
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print length, gsub("[^[:blank:]]", "&"), $0 }' |
sort -b -k 1,1n -k 2,2n |
cut -f 3-
```

The result of `length` is the length of the current line.  The result of `gsub()` is the number of substitutions made, and we replace each non-blank character with itself to count them.  The final `$0` that we print is the actual line.  These three parts are tab-delimited in the output.

The `sort` is then used to sort the data numerically on the first field and then the second field if the first fields are equal.  If the second fields are also identical, `sort` will make a lexicographical comparison of the two complete lines.

The `cut` at the end removes the added data from the lines, leaving the original lines to be outputted as the result.

Comment: Using forks on small input will goes longer than using *pure bash*. And if not mentionned in question, sample code use *pure bash*!

Comment: @F.Hauri Yes, your pure `bash` solution is perfectly fine for inputs up to a few kilobytes (the breakpoint is at 5 KB on my machine). Sorting any type of real-life data on a porduction system would be out of the question though, due to 1) efficiency, and 2) maintainability. You are, also discarding empty lines with your code, which I don't do with mine.

Comment: @F.Hauri Also note that in general I would agree with your that looping over `awk`, `sed` or the like is very bad indeed, but the code that I present literally has three forks. It's easy to understand and to maintain, and easily extended to other specifications.  A pure `bash` solution is far to easy to get wrong, especially when the given solution is not annotated or explained in any sort of way (not even to give the expected error conditions).

Comment: @F.Hauri Also note that the questioner says "I thought I would try to implement everything without relying too heavily on bash builtins", which means they didn't really set out to only use pure `bash` :-)